# Live edge slab “dent” protection

Tags: live-edge

I am finishing a live edge slab for a bathroom sink vanity countertop. The slab is absolutely perfect for the space, but had a chunk broken on the side of it. I sanded the chunk out as much as I can, and feathered in the depression so that it blends in pretty well. However, there’s still a slightly visible dent in the slab. I’d rather not keep sanding it out, so that the countertop doesn’t have an even deeper depression. However, I’m looking for suggestions on how to finish it off (epoxy seal? Just finish with the Rubio monocoat as is? A creative solution I haven’t thought of?) thanks! [image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. If you're going to be using Rubio Monocoat you need to respect how the product works with the wood, and being applied directly to bare wood is a requirement so that rules out sealing in advance with an epoxy.

Comment: Consider the dent part of the character of the piece and roll with that?

Comment: You could also have replaced the damaged part with a scab or patch, which can often add to the charm of a piece that is intended to show off wood and joinery.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to repair the dent with the steam technique.  Get a clothes iron and place a wet towel over the dent and use the iron to heat up the towel and generate hot water and steam.  Ideally the dented wood fibers expand and fill out the dent again.  Once it's dry the dent won't return.